# Syntax error near "tmp" in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise, hardware

I am trying to write a code for serial parallel conversion in Xilinx ise and VHDL language, but I get this error:

> Line 57: Syntax error near "tmp".

My VHDL Code is as below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY STP IS
    GENERIC(n : INTEGER :=10);
    PORT(din, clk, s: in std_logic; dout: out std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0));
END STP;

ARCHITECTURE BEHAV OF STP IS

    Signal tmp : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    Signal c : INTEGER := 0;

BEGIN

    PROCESS(s, clk)
    BEGIN
        IF (s'event AND s = '1' AND clk'event AND clk = '1' AND c = n) THEN
            tmp(c) <= din;
            dout <= tmp;
            c <= 0;
        ELSEIF(s'event AND s = '1' AND clk'event AND clk = '1')
            tmp(c) <= din;
            c <= c +1;
        ELSE
        END IF;

    END PROCESS;

END BEHAV;
```

Can somebody help me to handle this error?

Comment: I posted direct answer for your question, but I have to add, that your design is not correct for synthesis. You can only have one statement sensitive on clock edge, and no `ELSE` or `ELSIF` after that statement.

Comment: You can already see an error by looking at stackoverflow's syntax highlighting xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about `THEN` in line `ELSEIF(s'event AND s = '1' AND clk'event AND clk = '1')`.

There should also be `ELSIF` instead of `ELSEIF`. And actually, in this case there should be no such line, because your process can only have one statement sensitive on clock edge.

Comment: now i get this error:
Line 55: Syntax error near "THEN"

Comment: How exactly look this line now? Please, accept edits, or edit your code, so that it looks properly, and add this edited line below your question.

Comment: now its my code after edit:
ELSEIF(s'event AND s = '1' AND clk'event AND clk = '1') THEN
Should i use ELSEIF or ELSE IF?

Comment: You actually shouldn't use any of it. Look at my comment below your question. In other case there should probably be `elsif`.